# Read iOS 10 app logs programmatically

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa

I was using Apple's ASL framework read console logs from my app. Since this framework is now deprecated in iOS 10 for security reasons, NSLogs are routed via os_log.

Is there any way to programmatically read these logs now? It seems the log files are now stored as binaries instead of plain text files. Is it possible to get access these binaries and read them?